# Quota for attachments in RavenDB

Tags: size, limit, ravendb, attachment

In my RavenDB 2.5.2851 database I want to put attachments up to 2GB.

```
var store = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080" }.Initialize();
using (var reader = new StreamReader("test.attachment"))
{
    var id = "attachments/1";
    store.DatabaseCommands.PutAttachment(id, null, reader.BaseStream, null);
}
```

PutAttachment method started, but after 1,5 minutes the exception thrown: "The request was aborted: The request was cancelled".
I think this exception throws because of attachment size limits.

Is there the limit for attachment size? Can I configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a limit on attachment size, although big attachments aren't encouraged.
The issue is that you are probably hitting request time / size issues. You need to configure IIS properly.
Note that we never really meant attachments to hold very large values.

Comment: It was such an answer I feared. :)

Comment: I too am facing issues saving attachments of size greater than 10 MB. 
Can you please elaborate what settings should be checked related to "request time / size issues. You need to configure IIS properly."
@EvgeniyGryaznov How was your problem solved?

Comment: @Sachin, it was experiment to make decision about our technological stack. We didn't use RavenDB as the database in the end.